# how to interpret this scale?

Tags: current-measurement

I have been taking current lectures, but I'm confused about how must be taking the reads, using the scale selector as show next
[image]

there is 310 number, but this are 310mA?
I almost never take current.

Comment: I see a typical multimeter current range selector switch which includes 2000uA, 20 ma, 200ma, and 10A.positions. The switch is shown at the 20ma position.If your display reads 310 without any decimal points then something is wrong. Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Im taking again the lectures

Comment: @riccs_0x Is your meter an analog one with a needle that moves? Or is it digital?

Comment: @jonk, no its a small digital one

Comment: The maximum reading you should see on that range is 19.99 mA.  If you see 310, I would expect a decimal point after the 3, for a reading of 3.10 mA.  What current do you expect to measure?

Comment: @PeterBennett around 100mA

Comment: To measure 100 mA, turn the knob to 200m (milliamp). Then put the red lead in the "A" jack. The black lead stays in the "COM" jack. Don't forget to put the read lead back to the "V" jack when you are done. If you don't you can blow the fuse or worse.

Comment: I just checked it again under the 20mA scale, but I was reading 0.02 mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical cheap DMM is 3 ½ digit, 2000 Count LCD

so 20m=0 to +/-19.99 thus 310 is an invalid reading.

Compare meters in series for calibration test and beware of blown fuses.

Comment: Since It was for charging a mobile I try measuring with an app named "Ampere" and found it to be 310mA, so I'm guessing perhaps the knob as some sort of failure with the scales, and I used two different devices to check it up.